# Filter messages from rhc tail

Tags: openshift, tail, openshift-client-tools

When doing `rhc tail -a myApp`, I want to filter out all the lines with: `GET / 200`

I tried

```
rhc tail -a myApp | grep -V GET
```

but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a lowercase v, uppercase V seems to be version, at least on my mac...

```
 -V, --version
             Display version information and exit.

 -v, --invert-match
             Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.
```

Were you just getting the version of grep output to the screen?